# Why is my Faker in my Laravel app not registering?

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I'm trying to add Faker to my laravel site, however I seen to be running into an issue I can't quite put my finger on. I'm using docker with this also (side note). I am trying to make some seeds, but this is the error im getting. I was for sure that laravel had faker already installed within it. the issue is with line #25. When I don't put a \ in front of `$faker = Faker\Factory::create();`, I get faker error image #1. When I do put a \ in front of  `$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();`, I get faker error image #2. Just trying to get this to work at the end of the day.

Note, I have not pre installed Faker at all. I was informed it came built into laravel.

[image: Faker Error #2]

[image: Faker error #1]

Here is the entire error when you add the \ infront of Faker:

[With the \ in front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8qHe.jpg)

and here is the entire code on that same page:

[\Faker code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Skz.png)

Comment: What's the whole error on image #2? Also, you can use `fake()` helper if you're using Laravel 9 and above.

Comment: You must use `\Faker`, because if you don't, it will try to use the current namespace, that is basic PHP OOP, but please, do share the error on the `\Faker` usage

Comment: that is the entire error

Comment: I added new images to show the entire error and the entire page of code.

Comment: I figured out the issue! I was actually using faker on my variables in correctly I had to use it like :  'price' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 1000)' 

MAN, IT'S BEEN A DAY. Thank you for the time and effort put in to this guys. More than you know!

Answer (score 0):

It was my line 31. I wasn't using the randomFloat() correctly so it was causing those errors.

The correct way to use it was:

`'price' => $faker->randomFloat(2, 0, 1000)`